# making the next column stack up to the column above it bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want all the bootstrap columns to properly stack up to themselves like an image grid. Jsfiddle  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cpw8yk0c/)

Basically, I want Box 3 to be just beneath Box 1 and i also want the same column structure, i.e. Box 1, then Box 2, then Box 3. Instead of mixing Box 1 and Box 3 in one column.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Box 1</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Box 2 .....</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Box 3</div>
```

Instead of

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <section>Box 1</section>
    <section>Box 3</section>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Box 2 .....</div>
```

Why am i doing this ?

Because when the screen is a little wide , in jsfiddle when you stretch the output screen , there is a huge gap between box 3 and box 1 and when the screen is small , box1 comes first , then box 2 , then box 3 . 
This is desirable.

1) i want to show them in this order in mobile .

2) But in web,  there is a huge gap between box 1 and box 3 because of the height of box 2 . I want box 1 and box2 to be stacked .

How to achive both 1 and 2 situations . 
Can anyone point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put another row inside your column, and then put three full-width columns inside that inner row.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">Col 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have edited the answer to show my requirements . Thanks for taking the time to answer but it is not solving my problem